# How to Reverse a string using C?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I  am trying to run the below code in Visual Studio 2008. But at run time the program is throwing an error

> Unhandled exception at 0x002e1480 in reverseString.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x002e573c.

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end = str;
    char tmp;
    if (str)
    {
      while (*end)
      {
         ++end;
      }
      --end;

      while (str < end) 
      {
        tmp = *str;
        *str++ = *end; // Error Here
        *end-- = tmp;
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your great help.

Comment: How do you call reverse? how is str defined? maybe modifying string literal? otherwise it works fine: http://ideone.com/zC0Iip

Comment: It sounds plausible that the above function is called with a string literal which would fail!

Comment: @EdS. I think the OP is using C++, he just can't use `std` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use your reverse method with no issues, see below.  The problem must be in how you're using the char* that you're passing in.

```
int main()
{
    char str[] = "Hello World!";

    reverse(str);

    cout << str << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output

```
!dlroW olleH
```

Comment: you are right, I was passing the string directly to the function call.. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

It's trivial to reverse a string:

```
if (str) {
    std::reverse(str, str + strlen(str));
}
```

However, the precondition for this reversal to work is that `str` points to a writable string, i.e., it is declared as `char*` and is **not** initialized from a string literal! Although string literals can be used initialize `char*` objects, they do not necessarily point to writable memory (and on many contemporary system they do not point to writable memory).

In case you wonder how a naive implementation of `std::reverse()` could look like:

```
template <typename BiDirIt>
void reverse(BiDirIt begin, BiDirIt end) {
    for (; begin != end && begin != --end; ++begin) {
         swap(*begin, *end);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dietmar Kuhl, But I am trying to reverse the string without using any built-in methods..

Comment: `std::reverse()` isn't "built-in"! It is just a function template.

Comment: if (str) { // This line does not test if *str contains writable memory.

Comment: @user814064: that is correct. Nor is it common to test if the memory contains writable memory. It is one of the preconditions on calling this function.

Comment: Correct. But if the precondition is failing then that is the answer to why his program is failing.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::reverse(str, str + std::char_traits<char>::length(str));
```

Note that reversing a string will result in broken text for many languages and encodings.

Comment: Just wondering, is there any advantage to using that over `strlen`? I'm completely inexperienced and unknowledgeable when it comes to `std::char_traits`.

Comment: @chris: Not really, I could've just said `strrev`. I just showed the "C++" way of doing it, without using any C functions. :)

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, I have to +1 for the note at the very least. I do recall seeing another SO question where at least one answer went into detail about that and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do it from scratch

```
#include <iostream>

void reverse(char* input)
{
    int size = strlen(input);
    int half = size / 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < half; ++i)
    {
        char temp = input[size - i - 1];
        input[size - i - 1] = input[i];
        input[i] = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char word[] = "hello";
    reverse(word);
    std::cout << word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling it like so

```
char* mystr = "Hello";
reverse(mystr);
```

right? But you can't do that since reverse is modifying the string (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)) which leads to the access violation. Call it as others have suggested by using

```
char mystr[] = "Hello";
reverse(mystr)
```

That being said using std::reverse as suggested by the others is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, if you don't like/want iterator or reverse function.

```
 string revStr(string str){
        if (str.length() <= 1) {
            return str;
        }else{
            return revStr(str.substr(1,str.length()-1)) + str.at(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: hmm... When Knuth made his famous comment about premature optimization, I don't think he had this kind of blatant disregard for the computer's time in mind.

Comment: It's not incorrect. It just makes so many extra allocations (dependent on the length of the string) for a process which can easily be done in place.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley yeah